# Windows 10 Lock Screen Changing After Sign Out

Tags: windows-10

I set custom Lock Screen image in settings. It's all good but when in Sign Out through Ctrl+Alt+Del the screen is going to default, to the image displayed below. I'm the only user on my laptop and have all owner rights. How to set my picture to all causes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via Registry. That's a terrible idea, registry hacking is always a last resort, since it breaks so easily. All I can say is good luck; the key you want is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen`, but the format is completely opaque, and that's not all: The actual lock images are stored in a folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\{SID}\ReadOnly\LockScreen_B`, which is normally secured for SYSTEM only.

**Here are the workarounds:**

Requires a ps script and regedit

I deployed via logon script (bat file)

**Here is the ps script** - this makes all the settings for the logged in user and changes the Lock Screen:

---

```
# Change this to the path where you keep the desired background image
$imagePath = '(Path to Image, include single quotes)'

$newImagePath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($imagePath) + '\' + (New-Guid).Guid + [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($imagePath)
Copy-Item $imagePath $newImagePath
[Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen,Windows.System.UserProfile,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]
Function Await($WinRtTask, $ResultType) {
    $asTask = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod($ResultType)
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtTask))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
    $netTask.Result
}
Function AwaitAction($WinRtAction) {
    $asTask = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | ? { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and !$_.IsGenericMethod })[0]
    $netTask = $asTask.Invoke($null, @($WinRtAction))
    $netTask.Wait(-1) | Out-Null
}
[Windows.Storage.StorageFile,Windows.Storage,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
$image = Await ([Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync($newImagePath)) ([Windows.Storage.StorageFile])
AwaitAction ([Windows.System.UserProfile.LockScreen]::SetImageFileAsync($image))
Remove-Item $newImagePath
```

---

**Here is the Regedit to Change Login Screen**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Creative\S-1-0-0]
"RotatingLockScreenEnabled"=dword:00000000
"LockImageFlags"=dword:00000000
"LockScreenOptions"=dword:00000000
"CreativeId"=""
"PortraitAssetPath"="(Path to Image, include double quotes, remember to use \\ in between folders)"
"LandscapeAssetPath"="(Path to Image, include double quotes, remember to use \\ in between folders)"
```

---

**Here is the logon bat file**

```
CLS
@echo off

regedit /S (insert path to .reg file here)


IF NOT EXIST (Local Path storing image)  (
mkdir (Local Path storing image)
xcopy (From path) (Local Path storing image) /R /Y /I
) ELSE ECHO Applying Lock Screen

Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File  (Path to ps1 file)
Exit

EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reset Lock Screen Image Cache So That a Picture Can Be Set**

1. Backup Computer Before Trying these.
2. Open Regedit, go to (if exists, may not be applicable):

```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen\Creative
```

Set all flags to Set all "LockImageFlags" to `0` , Test (set image again).

3. Got to;

```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen\
```

[image: Lockscreen-Problem]
Delete all entries except; `FirstLockAfterOSInstall`, `LockAppAumId`, `SlideshowDirectoryPath1`, `SlideshowEnabled`, `SlideshowSourceDirectoriesSet`, `TileMigrated` & then test, (set image again). `(ignore settings in lower picture)`

[image: After Edit - Lock Screen Regedit]

4. If none of this works, then run both the above again if applicable then make and run this script as admin (to clear lockscreen user cache);

clear_lockscreen_cache.bat

```
call takeown /f C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData /R /D Y
call icacls C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData /grant "%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%":(F) /T /C
call Del /s /q C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData\*.*
call icacls C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\SystemData /reset /T /C
call exit
```

Set image again, this should now work.